# Как залить обновление на GooglePlay?

Tags: android, google-play

В гугле прочитал вот такие условия :
   Прежде чем публиковать обновление, проверьте, соблюдаются ли все перечисленные ниже условия.

1) Название пакета приложения обновленного APK и текущей версии совпадают.
2) Номер версии у обновления больше, чем у приложения. Подробнее…
3) Подписи обновленного APK и текущей версии совпадают.

Совпадения должны быть только в app.gradle?
а точнее вот эти строки :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "схожий id"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "версия выше прежней"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

еще подписка приложения..

Comment: и если да , должны ли совпадать applicationId и название самого пакета приложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `applicationId`
2) `versionCode`
3) сертификат подписи

По п.1 для уверенности можно заглянуть в готовый APK и проверить в манифесте корневой тег, атрибут `package`, вот по нему и проверяется при загрузке в Google Play.

`versionName` можете писать что угодно, это то что увидят ваши пользователи.

Comment: т.е. корневой пакет java кода должен совпадать с корневым пакетом прежней версиии?Просто не знаю название пакетов исходников прежней версии , дело в том что его писал другой программист.

Comment: Имена пакетов Java абсолютно не имеют значения. Только имя пакета приложения в манифесте. И совпадать не обязаны.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

В грэдле поднимаешь version name и version code приложения на 1.запаковываешь в консоли создаешь новый выпуск. Profit.